# Error running npm install in docker container

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

Trying to run npm install in my docker container. But all I get is this:

```
pm WARN package.json yeti-ui@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.1
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.31-moby
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/chrome
npm ERR! node -v v4.8.3
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm WARN prefer global marked@0.3.6 should
```

And this is how my docker image looks like (i am taking inspiration of a prebuilt:

```
FROM debian:sid
LABEL name="chrome-headless" \ 
        maintainer="Justin Ribeiro <justin@justinribeiro.com>" \
        version="1.4" \
        description="Google Chrome Headless in a container"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
  gnupg \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && curl -sSL https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub |     apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/     stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    google-chrome-stable \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl gnupg \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm git
    RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

    RUN groupadd -r chrome && useradd -r -g chrome -G audio,video chrome \
    && mkdir -p /home/chrome && chown -R chrome:chrome /home/chrome

USER chrome
WORKDIR /home/chrome
ADD .npmrc .npmrc
ADD package.json package.json
COPY . .
# RUN npm install (I have commented this out because the image could not be built for the same reason, so I thought it was easier to debug it if I manually try to run npm install when the container is up and running.)
```

I have found some forums stating that it might be solved by updating npm. I have tried to update my npm to the latest with this command npm install npm install npm@latest, even though the latest version is being installed it does not seem to use the latest one.

Comment: Can you share the content of your package.json?

Comment: it works now! Thanks though!

Comment: @ladyinwhite What did you do?